# how to prevent CUPS from proposing printers that are not listed in printer.conf?

Tags: cups

My `printers.conf` contains a short list of printers. When I open the *Print* menu of any application, a longer list of printers is shown. Besides those from `printers.conf`, there are some more from our corporate network. Through which mechanism does CUPS find those printers, which configuration files and parameters control this behavior, and how to switch it off?

My PC is fully administered by myself; it's running plain Debian. So the printer list is not pushed by the corporate IT. Rather my PC has retrieved this list from the network - against my intent, by some hidden mechanism.

[disclosure: also posted on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/854625]

Answer (score 3):

Cups is getting the printers on the local network using avahi broadcasting, I think. You can configure cups to not "browse" by editing `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` and changing the line `Browsing On` to

```
Browsing Off
```

and then restart the cups service.

Comment: How does the `Browsing` switch of `cups` relate to the package `cups-browsed`?

Comment: I don't know the details. This [description](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/cups-browsed) seems to suggest it is to provide compatibility for older clients and older remote cups servers using a different protocol than the newer "bonjour". There's some more about it [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS/Printer_sharing#Between_GNU.2FLinux_systems).